# Как избавиться от обязательных обявлений my?

Tags: perl

Начал писать на Perl, но вроде такого не должно быть, Perl просит меня все время на каждую переменную писать

```
my ..;
```

Это неудобно, конечно, и во-вторых, раньше я кое-что писал еще на 5.8, там это нафиг не надо было. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#use strict
```

Comment: но крайне не рекомендую))

Answer (score 2):

Отказ об обязательного объявления грозит трудновылавливаемыми проблемами связанными с простыми опечатками типа $WeryLongVar вместо $VeryLongVar. Крайне не рекомендую отключать strict;

Рекомендую перейти на PHP, где с этим никто не парится :)

Comment: Я вас всех прекрасно понимаю, но у меня кучка 3-строчников, где объявлять переменные - значить губить красоту.

Comment: одно дело - однострочник, который написан, чтобы сейчас бть исполненым и через 5 минут быть забытым, другое дело - даже три-четыре строки в файле, где уже можно напортачить.

Красота как раз должна быть в том, чтобы код хорошо читался и был понятным с первого взгляда, и use strict - это первый шаг к этому.

Comment: Может в РНР с этим можно и не парится, да проблема остаётся.
И ошибки в именах переменных. И хренова туча мусора в памяти...

Answer (score 1):

Приучите себя в начале перловых скриптов объявлять прагмы:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
```

Потом избавите себя от лишнего геммороя со скопами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```
my ($c, $d, $e, ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
no strict 'vars';
```